# How do I select and click with javascript on dom element without id?

Tags: javascript, dom, select

I've got some html and this html conatains somewhere deep in the dom the following div:

```
<div class="barbottomleft arrow " onclick="go('login')">
```

As you can see there is no id or whatever and it is a div among a lot of others. However, the onclick="go('login')" makes it unique in the whole document. Therefore I'd like to select it somehow and the click on it. Something like:

```
javascript:document.getElementById(\"element_id\").click();
```

However, this is not possible since it got no id but a unique onclick function call. So is there a possibility to select this element based on the function it is going to call?

Comment: Can someone pls explain the down votes? From what I can gather of the question. You want to find an element with a `go` function call, then execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a query selector with a lot of accuracy as such:

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('.barbottomleft.arrow[onclick="go(\'login\')"]');
```

This gets you an element with the two class and matching onclick attribute value. You could make it even more accurate by making sure it's a div:

```
var myElement = document.querySelector('div.barbottomleft.arrow[onclick="go(\'login\')"]');
```

I hope that helps.